# How to create a Macro that runs on selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want a code that makes it so that when I select any cell it cuts the contents of the cell below it . Add a space and then paste the other word
I hope to find a solution

[image: Like this]

When i select a cell "hello" and do a macro . Add space and "world"

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value`?

Answer (score 1):

`BigBen` has already provided the answer. In case you need to concatenate more than one cell below, you can try the following code.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ConcatCells()
    Dim arr, sTxt As String, rRng As Range
    With ActiveCell
        If .Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            Set rRng = Range(ActiveCell, .End(xlDown))
            sTxt = Join(Application.Transpose(rRng.Value))
            rRng.ClearContents
            .Value = sTxt
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]